# Extracting an arbitrary element from each row of a np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array of shape (n,m). I need to extract one element from each row, and I have another array of shape (n,) that gives the column index of the element I need. The following code does this, but it requires an explicit loop (in the form of a list comprehension.):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(range(12))
arr = arr.reshape((4,3))
keys = np.array([1,0,1,2])
#This is the line that I'd like to optimize
answers = np.array([arr[i,keys[i]] for i in range(len(keys))])
print(answers)
# [ 1  3  7 11]
```

Is there a built-in numpy (or pandas?) function that could do this more efficiently?

Comment: `arr[np.arange(4), keys]`

Comment: It's correct.  @GarethRees Please put that in the answer so you don't waste others time looking at something that hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is how @GarethRees suggested in the comments:

```
>>> arr[np.arange(4), keys]
array([1, 3, 7, 11])
```

There is another (not as good) solution that is a better alternative to using `arr[i, keys[i]] for i in range(len(keys))`.  Whenever you want both the index and the item from some iterable, you should generally use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
>>> np.array([arr[i, item] for i, item in enumerate(keys)])
array([1, 3, 7, 11])
```

Comment: Good point about enumerate since it's generally applicable. Thanks to Gareth for providing the initial answer in a comment. I'm accepting this one so that the question doesn't show as unanswered.